# Test Class with @invocableMethod

Tags: code-coverage, invocable-method

I wrote an Apex Class (with the help of some code I found on the internet, because i'm not a developer) to help automatically post some content to chatter with @mention. This Class had a @invocablemethod, so I can from process builder.

The code is working fine. But I just can't make it pass to the test for the code coverage.

Here is the code:

```
  public class PostToChatter 
  {

  @InvocableMethod

  public static void PostToChatter (list<String> params) {     

  // Fetch the Movimentacao__c record from the parameter and fetch the   Casos__c details

  Movimentacoes__c mov = 
   [select Id, Processo_Relacionado_ao_Acompanhamento__c, Conteudo__c  from Movimentacoes__c mov where id = :params[0]];

  Id casosId = Id.valueOf(mov.Processo_Relacionado_ao_Acompanhamento__c);

  string conteudo = mov.conteudo__c; 

  //Adding a Text post

  ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
  ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new >   ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
  ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new >   ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
  ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new >  ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

  messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new   List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

  mentionSegmentInput.id = '0F9630000004KqY';
  messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

  textSegmentInput.text = ' ' + 'Há um novo andamento nesse caso: ' + conteudo;
  messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

  feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
  feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
  feedItemInput.subjectId = casosId;

  ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);
 }
 }
```

And here one of my @isTest tries:

```
 @isTest 
 public class TestAndamentosNoChatter {
 private static testMethod void doTest () {

 Test.startTest();

 Movimentacoes__c mov = new Movimentacoes__c ();
 mov.Processo_Relacionado_ao_Acompanhamento__c = 'a073600000ASBcV';
 mov.Conteudo__c = 'testando123';

 insert mov;

 Test.stopTest();
 }
 }
```

The error that i'm receiving most of the time is: Error Occurred: An Apex error occurred: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

On the Process Builder site, the Call Apex is set like:

Apex Class:
AndamentosNoChatter

Variables:
Field* = params    Type* Reference     Value* [Movimentacoes__c].Id

But, like i said, the process are working; i just can't write a valid test class.

Thanks very much for any help!